# How to add my directshow filter into filter graph

Tags: c++, filter, render, directshow

I have written a custom directshow filter, derived from directshow CBaseRenderer class. The following code is my filter.

```
class CRenderSamples : public CBaseRenderer
{
// private data members
// constructors and destructors are private, need to use CoCreateInstance(.)
protected:
    //BYTE *m_pCopyBuffer;
    CMediaType m_MediaType;

    CRenderSamples(LPUNKNOWN pUnk,HRESULT *phr);
    virtual ~CRenderSamples();

public:
    //The CheckMediaType method determines if the 
    //filter accepts a specific media type.
    virtual HRESULT CheckMediaType(const CMediaType *pMediaType);

    // The DoRenderSample method renders a sample.
    virtual HRESULT DoRenderSample(IMediaSample *pMediaSample);

    // Instantiate filter object
    static CUnknown * WINAPI CreateInstance(LPUNKNOWN pUnk, HRESULT *phr);

};
```

I have successfully built the filter and register it in COM. Alos, I have tested my filter in conjunction with a pushsourcedesktop filter in GraphEdit and it works as expected. The problem comes in coding.  I am a bit confused about what type of pointer should be used for instantiating the filter object. If I instantiate the filter object with an IBaseFilter pointer, everything works fine but I cannot use DoRenderSamBple() method I implement in my own filter. However, if I use CBaseRenderer, the AddFilter() function generates runtime error since its first parameter requires a IBaseFilter pointer. The following code is my app.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <ObjBase.h>
#include <DShow.h>
#include <initguid.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <streams.h>
#include "PushGuids.h"

//#pragma once
#pragma comment(lib,"Strmiids.lib") 

static const GUID CLSID_RENDER_SAMPLES = {0x9ddd8a2a, 0xa66c, 0x423a, { 0xa7, 0xb1, 
                    0xc3, 0x22, 0xae, 0xbc, 0x1c, 0x1e } };


int CALLBACK WinMain(
  _In_  HINSTANCE hInstance,
  _In_  HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
  _In_  LPSTR lpCmdLine,
  _In_  int nCmdShow
){
    IGraphBuilder *pGraph = NULL;
    IMediaControl *pControl = NULL;
    IMediaEvent*   pEvent = NULL;


    HRESULT hr = CoInitialize(NULL);
    if (FAILED(hr)) {
         MessageBox(NULL,TEXT("ERROR - Could not initialize COM library."),TEXT("Error!"),MB_OK);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }


    hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_FilterGraph, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, 
            IID_IGraphBuilder, (void **)&pGraph);
    if (FAILED(hr)) {
        MessageBox(NULL,TEXT("Could not create the Filter Graph    Manager."),TEXT("Error!"),MB_OK);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    hr = pGraph -> QueryInterface(IID_IMediaControl, (void **)&pControl);
    hr = pGraph -> QueryInterface(IID_IMediaEvent, (void **)&pEvent);


    IBaseFilter* pPushSourceDesktop = 0;
    hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_PushSourceDesktop, 0, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
                IID_IBaseFilter, (void**)&pPushSourceDesktop);

    if (FAILED(hr)) {
        MessageBox(NULL,TEXT("Could not create PushSourceDesktop filter."),TEXT("Error!"),MB_OK);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }


    hr = pGraph -> AddFilter(pPushSourceDesktop, L"PushSourceDesktop"); 
    if (FAILED(hr)) {
        MessageBox(NULL,TEXT("Could not add PushSourceDesktop filter."),TEXT("Error!"),MB_OK);
        return 0;
    }

    //IBaseFilter *pRenderSamples;  
    CBaseRenderer *pRenderSamples;
    //IBaseFilter *pRenderer;
    hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_RENDER_SAMPLES,0,CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
                IID_IBaseFilter, (void**)&pRenderSamples);
    if (FAILED(hr)) {
        MessageBox(NULL,TEXT("Could not instantiate RenderSamples."),TEXT("Error!"),MB_OK);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }else{
        MessageBox(NULL,TEXT("Successfully instantiate RenderSamples filter."),TEXT("Success!"),MB_OK);
    }

    hr = pGraph -> AddFilter(pRenderSamples, L"Render Samples"); 
    if (FAILED(hr)) {
        MessageBox(NULL,TEXT("Could not add RenderSamples filter."),TEXT("Error!"),MB_OK);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }else{
        MessageBox(NULL,TEXT("Successfully add RenderSamples filter."),TEXT("Success!"),MB_OK);
    }

    IPin **ppPushPinDesktop = new (IPin*);
    hr = pPushSourceDesktop -> FindPin(L"1", ppPushPinDesktop); 
    if (FAILED(hr)) {
        MessageBox(NULL,TEXT("Could not find pin of filter PushSourceDesktop."),TEXT("Error!"),MB_OK);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    IPin **ppRenderSamples = new (IPin*);
    hr = pRenderSamples -> FindPin(L"In", ppRenderSamples); 
    switch(hr)
    {
        case S_OK:
            MessageBox(NULL,TEXT("Successfully find pin."),TEXT("Success!"),MB_OK);
            break;
        case E_POINTER:
            MessageBox(NULL,TEXT("Null pointer argument."),TEXT("Null Pointer!"),MB_OK);
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        case VFW_E_NOT_FOUND:
            MessageBox(NULL,TEXT("Could not find a pin with this identifier."),TEXT("Error!"),MB_OK);
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    hr = pGraph -> Connect(*ppPushPinDesktop,*ppRenderSamples);
    switch(hr){
        case S_OK:
            MessageBox(NULL,TEXT("Successfully connect PushSourceDesktop and RenderSamples."),TEXT("Success!"),MB_OK);
            break;
        case VFW_S_PARTIAL_RENDER:
            MessageBox(NULL,TEXT("Partial success; some of the streams from this pin use an unsupported format."),
                        TEXT("Partial success!"),MB_OK);
            break;
        case E_ABORT:
            MessageBox(NULL,TEXT("Operation aborted."),TEXT("Aborted!"),MB_OK);
            break;
        case E_POINTER:
            MessageBox(NULL,TEXT("NULL pointer argument."),TEXT("NULL Pointer!"),MB_OK);
            break;
        case VFW_E_CANNOT_CONNECT:
            MessageBox(NULL,TEXT("No combination of intermediate filters could be found to make the connection."),TEXT("Aborted!"),MB_OK);
            break;
        case VFW_E_NOT_IN_GRAPH:
            MessageBox(NULL,TEXT("At least one of the filters is not in the filter graph."),TEXT("Filter no in filter graph"),MB_OK);
            break;
        default:
            MessageBox(NULL,TEXT("Unknow error"),TEXT("Error!"),MB_OK);
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    pControl -> Release();
    pEvent -> Release();

    (*ppPushPinDesktop) -> Release();
    pPushSourceDesktop -> Release();

    pRenderSamples-> Release();
    (*ppRenderSamples)->Release();

    pGraph -> Release();
    CoUninitialize(); 

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Could anyone give any idea to solve such problem. Thank your so much!!!

Answer (score 0):

Since you shaped your filter as a COM class/object, you should be working with COM interface pointers from there. When you add the filter into graph and start streaming, quite often you don't need to have any custom direct interaction between controlling app and the filter.

If you however want to have it, you need to implement an additional interface on your filter/pin (so called "private interface" in terms that it's available to public but it known to your app and the filter only so noone else is using it), and necessary methods on it. The application will obtain the pointer via `QueryInterface` and will be able to call methods as needed.

As a part of normal DirectShow streaming, renderer receives samples via standard path `IPin::Receive` and it does not need you cal do any external calls from the controlling application.

Comment: Yeap. But the problem is should I use IBaseFilter or CBaseRenderer to instantiate my filter object in the function CoCreateInstance? Because  the function AddFilter() requires a IBaseFilter pointer as its input.

Comment: You request pointer of "type" `IID_IBaseFilter`, so it should definitely be `IBaseFilter` and nothing else.

Comment: Is there any way to instantiate a CBaseRenderer type while bypassing the conflict in the input of AddFilter?

Comment: Short answer: No. Longer answer: you are always instantiating the same type `CRenderSamples`, however you are only allowed to use COM pointers like `IBaseFilter`, and you are not allowed to use base C++ classes.